# Time complexity for easy nested loop

Tags: c, time-complexity

```
for (int i=0; i<=N-1; ++i) {
    for (int j=i+1; j<=N; ++j) {
        SOME O(1) code;
    }
}
```

I thought this code is O(nlogn) time complexity but my friend says this is O(n^2) time complexity. Which one is right? I am struggling with this....

Comment: It's O(n^2). Why do you think it's O(n log n)?

Comment: The second loops will run N + N-1 + N-2 + ... 1 times = N(N+1)/2 times.

Comment: @kim The total number of iterations is N * ( N + 1 ). So the complexity is O( N ^ 2 )

Comment: @VladfromMoscow isn't it supposte to be N * (N - 1) ?

Comment: @GRC It is not important.

Answer (score 3):

Understand it like this:

when i=0, j will run from 1 to N = N times 
when i=1, j will run from 2 to N = N-1 times 
..... 
when i=N-1, j will run for N = 1 time

So, complexity = 1+2+3+....+N = N*(N+1)/2 = ((N^2)+N)/2
As you can see, this is in order of n^2.

Comment: oops sorry, will correct it.